# Automatic JSDoc tag generation

Tags: javascript, code-generation, abstract-syntax-tree, jsdoc

Given a *clean* js file is there a tool that can update the file by generating JSDoc-style comment tags automatically?

For example, before:

```
function myfunc(foo, bar) {
     // do stuff with foo & bar
     return result;
}
```

and after:

```
/** 
   @todo Complete documentation.
   @param {object} foo - Add description for parameter foo
   @param {object} bar - Add description for parameter bar
*/
function myfunc(foo, bar) {
     // do stuff with foo & bar
     return result;
}
```

Comment: You should be able to do a bad version of this with Perl.  What's wrong with that?

Comment: Nothing. I was thinking of writing a tool based around recast (https://github.com/benjamn/recast) but I want to check first if there is a such tool already out there to avoid reinventing the wheel.